# How to design a form with more than 30 mandatory field inputs

Tags: usability, forms, user-centered-design

I need to solve a situation where I have to design forms with 30-40 input fields (most of them are required) in order to complete the task and generate a final output. 
With th design principle "**Minimum interaction, maximum output**"
Following approach I am thinking to handle this situation:

1. Implement predictive search option where ever field require
2. Split the 40 fields in logical grouping page and allow user to submit form in progressive closure way
3. Use conditional logic to shorten forms
4. carefully use the list, radio button, checkboxes and dropdown
5. Use the visual cues and icons to make form field more intuitive

Can you suggest me any other way to handle this situation in better way. Note 40 fields is on single product and 25 different product have similar kind of mandatory field to fill to accomplish task. Please suggest any different perspective.

Comment: Before I try answering, could you tell me what kind of form it is? Because close to 30 mandatory fields seems high. Also, I feel like your question holds most of the answer.

Comment: Please, see my answer

Comment: I am dealing with insurance client where lot of information need to provide before actual estimate quote to be generated for customer approval.Hope you understand the context of the long mandatory form.

Answer (score 1):

** You should combine all of these points. **

- Start with grouping, group fields based on the objective or their
  importance. Put most important points at the beginning.

  Break the page in steps you can use a popular layout preferred by
  e-commerce. Start with basic details, more deep, finance, etc.
- To reduce frustration use default values, radio, checkboxes and keep
  typing work as minimum as possible. It can result in bad user
  experience on touch screens.

Finally, I will say if possible keep some fields for later. Use them for gamification. I have seen a few sites implementing this.

First, they let you signup with necessary information and then show a extend trial or get bonus points to ask more information.

Comment: I am dealing with insurance client where lot of information need to provide before actual estimate quote to be generated for customer approval.Hope you understand the context of the long mandatory form.

Comment: @rohitranjan can you share the fields. I mean if possible a rough page so that I can make a mockup. It will also help me in future designs.

Answer (score 1):

The most frustrating thing for a user is to work for nothing (maximum interaction, minimum output). A lot of things can happen while filling out a form, and there is a slight chance that all the information entered would vanish somehow, for whatever reason.

The very one thing to do **is to save the current progress**. It is work from the user and the worst for him is to see it gone from a single mistake.

Another thing to understand is that users do no want to engage unless there is a good reason. So whenever you can, try to **explain why this group of fields is required** and how does it bring any value for the end user.

Then, you may want to consider general guidelines for forms:

- No asking the same information twice
- Making the best guess for usual inputs
- Providing the most used options on top for long dropdowns
- Grouping related fields
- Hiding conditional inputs when not needed
- Avoiding placeholders inside inputs
- Giving an explanation on how to get the information
- Using the same terminology than the users

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the most of your points. Another could be: make it fun to fill the form! I've actualy got pretty good results with quite a long form when I put some interesting copy as a guidance through it. The copy can do really a lot!

Also already mentioned gamification would be the best thing, but very hard to do in a good way.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I would say you need to reconsider everything you do based on end user feedback. Just start with the simplest solution possible. I believe it is grouping.
And then look and the data, see duplications, dependencies and patterns. Without real user data and field specifics, it is impossible give a better answer to your question.

Comment: I am dealing with insurance client where lot of information need to provide before actual estimate quote to be generated for customer approval.Hope you understand the context of the long mandatory form.